# Transforming single-row result set into an associative array

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, associative-array

Say, I have the following query:

```
select 1 foo, 2 bar, 3 baz from dual;
```

Basically, this query always returns me one row. I need to create an associative array from that, one of this kind:

```
arr('foo') = 1;
arr('bar') = 2;
arr('baz') = 3;
```

I know that result set is only one row. I don't know neither columns amount nor columns names.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**upd:**

A friend of mine found a nice and elegant, XML-involving solution:

```
  SELECT
   XMLTYPE(EXTRACT(VALUE(T), '/*') .GETSTRINGVAL()) .GETROOTELEMENT() NODE,
   EXTRACTVALUE(COLUMN_VALUE, '/*') NODEVALUE
    FROM
   TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(XMLTYPE((CURSOR
   (
      --this is the query that needs to be transformed
      SELECT
       *
        FROM
       some_table
       WHERE some_table.id = 123

   )
   )) .EXTRACT('/ROWSET/ROW/*'))) T;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple package which populates an associative array from a key value pair table.  This is the easy case.

```
create or replace package dynaa as
    procedure pop;
    procedure print;
end;
/

create or replace package body dynaa as

    type aa is table of number
        index by varchar2(30);
    this_aa aa;

    procedure pop
    is
    begin
        for r in ( select * from t42 )
        loop
            this_aa (r.id) := r.col1;
        end loop;
    end pop    ;

    procedure print
    is
        idx varchar2(30);
    begin
        idx := this_aa.first();
        while idx is not null
        loop
            dbms_output.put_line(idx ||'='||this_aa(idx));
            idx := this_aa.next(idx);
        end loop;
    end print;
end;
/
```

And it works quite neatly....

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> exec dynaa.pop

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec dynaa.print
DAISY HEAD MAISIE=6969
FOX IN SOCKS=4242
MR KNOX=2323

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

But what you want is more complicated: to dynamically populate the array without knowing the projection of the query.  The following is a horribly simplistic implementation, which will work if the table in question contains a single row.  It can easily be extended to handle a table with multiple rows.

We overload the `POP()` procedure thus:

```
procedure pop
    ( tabname user_tab_columns.table_name%type );

procedure pop
    ( tabname user_tab_columns.table_name%type );
is
    n number;
begin
    for r in ( select column_name 
               from user_tab_columns
               where table_name = tabname)
    loop
        execute immediate 'select '||r.column_name||' from '||tabname into n;
        this_aa (r.column_name) := n;
    end loop;
end pop    ;
```

So, this works too:

```
SQL> exec dynaa.pop('T23')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> exec dynaa.print
COL1=2323
COL2=4242
COL3=6969

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

I'm not too worried about the performance hit of initialising the array in such a shonky fashion.  Given that the record stays in cache it isn't too bad.  And if you're calling `POP()` so often that performance does become an issue then you probably shouldn't be using an associative array in the first place: either regular look-ups or resultset caching would be better options.

Answer (score 1):

A very short answer is to look at old-style (pre Oracle 9) dynamic SQL using the `DBMS_SQL` package.  You can use the `DESCRIBE_COLUMNS` to get the number (and data types) of the columns and `COLUMN_VALUE` for every entry in the PL/SQL table returned by `DESCRIBE_COLUMNS` to fetch each column value individually.

After that, it's pretty easy to turn a row into an associative array.